# Rudin's RCA Theorem $3.17$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

There are the definitions which we need for the proof of the theorem:
[image]
[image]

There is the theorem:

If $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, then $C_0(X)$ is the completion of $C_c(X)$, relative to the metric defined by the supremum norm

$||f||$ $=$ $ sup |f(x)| x \in X$.

There is the proof:
We have to show that $(a)$ $C_c(X)$ is dense in $C_0(X)$ and $(b)$ $C_0(X)$ is a complete metric space.

The proof of the $(a)$ is understandable.
Here is the proof of the $(b)$:
To prove $(b)$, let {$f_n$} be a Cauchy sequence in $C_0(X)$, i.e., assume that {$f_n$} converges uniformly. Then its pointwise limit function $f$ is continuous.
Given $\epsilon$ $\gt$ $0$, there exists an $n$ so that $||f_n - f||$ $\lt$ $\epsilon$/$2$ and there is a compact set $K$ so that $|f_n(x)|$ $\lt$ $\epsilon$/$2$ outside $K$. Hence $|f(x)|$ $\lt$ $\epsilon$ outside $K$, and we have proved that $f$ vanishes at infinity. Thus $C_0(X)$ is complete.

I don't understand how do we conclude that $|f(x)|$ $\lt$ $\epsilon$ outside $K$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that $n$ and for any $x$ outside $K$, we have both

- $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le\|f_n-f\|<\epsilon/2$ and
- $|f_n(x)|<\epsilon/2,$

hence $|f(x)|<\epsilon,$ by triangular inequality.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in K^\complement$, you have $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):|f_n(x)|<\frac\varepsilon2$. Therefore\begin{align}|f(x)|&=\left|\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\right|\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n(x)|\\&\leqslant\frac\varepsilon2\\&<\varepsilon.\end{align}